# Jhipster : unable to run gulp

Tags: npm, gulp, jhipster

I am trying to run gulp on my jhipster application but I am getting this error.
Any idea where this issue can come from?
I am using a macbook, I haven't been able to install bower and gulp without sudo. Without sudo I have EACCESS errors.

```
pm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path /Users/m/.npm/statuses/1.3.1
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/me/.npm/statuses/1.3.1'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/me/.npm/statuses/1.3.1'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/me/.npm/statuses/1.3.1',
npm ERR!   parent: 'http-errors' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/dev/planning/npm-debug.log
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-rev'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/dev/planning/gulpfile.js:5:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm throws error without sudo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)